# change the order of sup and inf

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples, supremum-and-infimum

I know that for a series $a_{m,n}\ge 0$
$$\sup_m \inf_n a_{m,n}\neq \inf_n\sup_m  a_{m,n}$$

But I can't find a counterexample. Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to define $a_{m,n}$ differently for $m>n$ and in another way for $m\le n$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks

Comment: user166445: If you are able to solve your problem using that hint, perhaps you could post the solution as an answer. (Answering your own question is [specifically encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) on SE.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Sleziak's hint:

$a_{m,n}=1_{m>n}+2_{m\le n}$

$$1=\sup_m \inf_n a_{m,n}\neq \inf_n\sup_m  a_{m,n}=2$$

Comment: I will just add that more common notation seems to be
$a_{m,n}=\begin{cases}
    1 & m>n, \\
    2 & m\le n.
  \end{cases}$
See [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5025) to learn how to typeset things like this.

Answer (score 4):

This reminded me of the difference between $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, so I thought of
$$
a_{m,n}=(-1)^{m+n}
$$
where
$$
\sup_m\operatorname*{inf\vphantom{p}}_na_{m,n}=-1
$$
and
$$
\operatorname*{inf\vphantom{p}}_n\sup_ma_{m,n}=+1
$$